# Python Class definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x

deck is empty list. Is deck an **Attribute** of object of Deck class or deck is an **Object /Instance** of the Deck class?

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = [ ]
```

Comment: In your code `deck` is an attribute of `Deck` holding an instance of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case , deck is a list which is an attribute of deck class.

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
```

If it would have been like this, then it would have been an Object/Instance of Deck class

```
deck = Deck()  ----- > Here you create an instance of Class.
```

Answer (score 0):

deck is an attribute of instance of class Deck.

if you create one instance of Deck, name also deck.
It means you have an instance deck of Deck, and this deck will have an attribute deck whose value is an empty list.

How to tell the difference ?

- use deck for an instance of class Deck
- use deck.deck for that empty list.
- use self.deck in class definition because there maybe lot of different instance.